# How to store <key, value> pair in a sorted form in java

Tags: java

I want to store 200  pair in  form. Is there anyway I can sort them according to value at the time of inserting?
Is there anyway this can be done in java?

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for a TreeMap.

Comment: @Corbin: TreeMap is sorted on the keys not the values.

Comment: @BheshGurung Ah yeah, oops.  I just assumed he meant by key.

Comment: how about self balancing tree?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A plain HashMap is unordered, and cannot be sorted.

Furthermore, there is no data structure that I'm aware of that is capable of sorting based on a state of objects that no longer exists.

What you need to do is create a second data structure to hold the values in order based on their values at insertion time.  (And even that assumes that NO values are changed during the insertion phase ... because if they are you won't be able to order them at all.)

Alternatively, you could extract the HashMap's value set to a list, and sort that.  But (obviously) you can't sort the values based on a state that no longer exists.

---

Aside: your data structure requirements are bordering on describing an "intractable" problem; i.e. one for which no sensible solution exists.  This might be because you have misstated them, or it might be that they are real.  Either way, this might be indicating that you need to rethink your entire approach to the larger problem you are trying to solve here.

Comment: I have a set of 200 values and a key. I want to determine top k elements from them. So I thought storing them in a hashmap will be a better option......